# Архивирование директорий при помощи PclZip любого объема и файлов любого размера

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, товарищи, коллеги!

Не буду писать конкретный код, так как вариантов может быть тысяча, да и ни к чему это, скорее требуется проанализировать логику и понять - возможно\невозможно, целесообразно\не целесообразно - лично мне это интересно и хочется реализовать. А так как я человек разумный (на мой взгляд :) ), то конечно же мне хочется посоветоваться, подумать, так сказать предварительно подготовить почву...

Появилась у меня задача, я в раздумьях, что посоветуете, как посчитаете, разумная ли вообще идея\мысль:

Сразу скажу, требуется решение, которое должно работать на любом или практически любом шаред хостинге...

Есть класс [pclzip](http://www.phpconcept.net), он умеет архивировать папки\подпапки\и все файлы, лежащие в них.

1. Необходимо научить скрипт архивировать большие файлы так, чтобы не отваливался `memory_limit(), max_execution_time()`. Естественно, если загрузить в память файл размером 1.5-3 гб, все повиснет и отвалится. :)
2. Необходимо предварительно сканировать весь объем данных, лежащий в папках, - а их может быть и 100 гигабайт и терабайт.

В связи с этим появились 2 серьезные проблемы:

1. Время выполнения скрипта "`max_execution_time`":
   На мой взгляд, решение простое, подавать массив имен файлов на архивацию частями с помощью функции fsockopen - то есть запускать скрипт по принципу "сам себя" после обработки каждой итерации, дополнительно используя на всякий случай `ignore_user_abort(true)`, - хотя я тестировал, работает вроде и без этого параметра "на следующих итерациях от первого".
2. Подпроблема, массив с именами ведь тоже весит каких-то байтов (строка ведь весит) - а если их будет слишком много (имен файлов), то за раз все просканировать не удастся, все тот же `memory_limit или max_execution_time` отвалятся:
   Возможное решение в моей голове, сканировать папки частями, но что-то я никак не могу найти даже маленького примера - и видимо, попахивает эта задача пляской с бубном, или проблема просто в том, что я еще пока сам бубен... :)

В связи с этим у меня возникло пару вопросов:

1. Какие варианты смогут решить задачу с копированием из одной папки на сервере в другую папку\архив zip того же сервера большой файл размером от 1 гб, есть ли возможность загружать память поэтапно, копируя файл последовательно\частями? И дополнительный актуальный вопрос по этому поводу - можно ли прочитать часть большого файла в одной итерации fsockopen, а в другой дочитать оставшуюся часть файла?
2. Как просканировать гигантскую директорию с кучей поддиректорий в разных итерациях и в итоге сложить все дерево папок и файлов в текстовый файл например\или в бд?

Буду рад любому логически развернутому ответу!

**Обновление**

Да, кстати, по поводу ограничения размера одного архива вопрос не стоит, ведь можно разбить архив на части, скажем, при fat32 по 3.5 гб. А на ntfs по 5 - 10 гб.

Вообще, какая самая распространенная файловая система на шаредах, подскажите?

**Мысли по комментарию от Etki**

Etki, благодарю за внимание!

Цитирую:
Да, лучше всего просто вызвать системную команду (не удивлюсь, если copy() и так все правильно сделает), можно открыть через fopen() и читать/писать по N байт.

Комментирую:
Да, согласен, стандарные функции должны справиться, я тоже это предполагал... Просто в самом классе pclzip используется функционал декомпрессии файлов - по этой причине сам автор высказывается следующим образом: http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/faq#faq03 - то есть, он тут хочет сказать, много мелких файлов пожалуйста, а вот крупные файлы зло, не совсем понял - крупные файлы зло в связке с большим количеством файлов в одном потоке, или просто сами по себе крупные файлы он не может обрабатывать... Вот это меня и смутило во всем этом процессе... Вообще **что есть "декомпрессия файла на php" - если конкретно, простонародным языком ?**

Цитирую:
Мне сложно представить ситуацию, когда не хватит памяти на список файлов. Но если такая проблема возникнет, у нее вполне аналогичное решение: список файлов по мере заполнения скидывается в самый обычный временной файл, а при добавлении файлов в архив этот временной файл построчно читается (насколько понимаю, SplFileObject уже реализует необходимый итератор), в результате чего в памяти единомоментно висит всего один путь к файлу.

Комментирую:
Решение вполне реальное, но какое то кастыльное - файлы ведь могут писаться, удаляться - из-за этого придется постоянно думать об этом списке, ад. А разбить на части сканирование директорий - вот это было бы "**железобетонным инструментом**" - именно этого я и хочу добиться...

Цитирую:
Он должен выполняться как отдельный процесс, если к этому обязательно надо прикрутить веб-морду - gearman в помощь.

Комментирую:
С этим вопросом проблем вообще нет, можно дернуть даже ajax-сом, просто дать старт входному файлу, а все остальное php выполнит сам, главное простукивать его время от времени - завершен ли процесс, если нет, то работает ли, по этим моментам есть такой материал: http://petukhovsky.com/simple-web-socket-on-php-daemon/

Есть смысл поковырять это: ZipArchive - быть может это окажется даже более гибким решением... Ведь сам класс pclzip - написан довольно корявенько, хотя возможно его по другому и не напишешь, его я выбрал по причине хорошей скорости, класс очень быстрый...

Вобщем, хотелось бы услышать еще какие нибудь интересные варианты, что бы после потестировать сразу весь пул идей\мыслей...

Etki, еще раз благодарю!

Comment: > вот это было бы "железобетонным инструментом" 

Между двумя сканированиями появилась пачка новых файлов. Как определить, где сканирование остановилось в прошлый раз?

Эта проблема, конечно, решается, но вносит дополнительный геморрой. Потерянные файлы (которые дописываются после анализа) будут всегда.

> С этим вопросом проблем вообще нет, можно дернуть даже ajax-сом

Я там довольно много написал, почему этого делать в режиме веб-сервера нельзя.

Comment: @Gektar По поводу `ZipArchive`. Возможно, Вам здорово упростит задачу вот эта [библиотека/абстракция](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem). Один из адаптеров как раз-таки [ZipArchive](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/master/src/Adapter/Zip.php)

Comment: Тут уже вопрос скорее в криворукости пользователя, чем вопрос программирования. Мы в программах(например в ворде) делаем сохранение только после того как внесли все нужные изминения. Так что этот вопрос даже не стоит поднимать - не принципиально. Задача - нужен автономный независимый от костылей сканер на php.

И про запуск через веб интерфейс - это как раз принципиальная необходимость, нужно архивировать по требованию. В прочем, дергая скрипт я лишь говорю процессу - запустись и выполни все что мне нужно без меня... fsockopen как раз позволит это притворить в жизнь...

Comment: А простукивать обязательно придется, так как сервер не есть гарант выполнения задачи на которую может потребоваться 2 - 3 дня... ) Его могут перезагрузить, он может повиснуть, и т.д. Полагаться на чудо не приходится - нужен железобетонный инструмент!

Comment: @Gektar, ну вот вы к "железобетонному" инструменту по факту привзяываете еще и воркера веб-сервера (и, наверняка, fpm), который вполне себе может взять и упасть (если бы я писал сервер, у меня бы воркеры гарантированно убивались на таком времени выполнения запроса). Там нужен запуск в отдельном процессе, хоть gearman, хоть как, банальный лог и готовность сглотнуть ошибку и продолжить дальше, оставив соответствующую запись в логе.

> Задача - нужен автономный независимый от костылей сканер на php.

Итераторы файловой системы - это самое бескостыльное решение вообще.

Comment: @Gektar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: **ну вот вы к "железобетонному" инструменту по факту привзяываете еще и воркера веб-сервера (и, наверняка, fpm)**

Начинается какой-то флуд\споры, которые только засоряют пространство - Вы бы лучше предложили интересный вариант. А по поводу неполноценности описанной теории говорить рано, ведь, помимо грубых инструментов, существует тонкая смикалка программиста - в большенстве случаев именно она и решает задачу на "железобетонно". "**Там нужен запуск в отдельном процессе**" - так логика это и предполагает, каждая итерация будет происходить в отдельном процессе\потоке... :)

Comment: > Вы бы лучше предложили интересный вариант.

Я уже сказал про gearman. Очереди в любой их реализации.

> тонкая смикалка программиста - в большенстве случаев именно она и решает задачу на "железобетонно"

смекалка, большинстве

Ни одна смекалка не сможет помочь, если стороннее приложение, возможно, убьет свое процесс. Я же предлагаю просто отказаться от шатких моментов.

> "Там нужен запуск в отдельном процессе" - так логика это и предполагает

Нет, она предполагает запуск в веб-воркере. И потому и появляется риск задосить сервер или потерять процесс в середине выполнения.

Comment: Это Вы про ссылку http://petukhovsky.com/simple-web-socket-on-php-daemon/, это просто пример... Даже если использовать воркер с определенным количеством потоков, его нужно правильно контролировать. Если у программиста кривые руки, то он напишет так, чтобы досилось, висло и т.д. А если программу спроектировать правильно (логику) как мы например это делаем с базами данных - то все будет прекрасно работать - без осечек...

Я не собираюсь с Вами спорить, мне это совершенно не нужно. Если у Вас есть интересные мысли по теме вопроса, кроме той мысли которую Вы уже высказали, буду рад рассмотреть ее

Answer (score 2):

Пара комментариев (которые в обычный комментарий не влезут)

С условно-бесконечными ресурсами (которые физически превышают ресурсы машины) есть только один способ работы - атомарный, когда берется какая-то единица ресурса (в идеале - минимально возможная) и обрабатывается, после чего обработчик о ней благополучно забывает и приступает к следующей. Таким образом можно обрабатывать, например, условно-бесконечные сетевые потоки, считывая из них по N байт - таким образом можно передать очень большое количество запросов, разделенных некоторым разделителем, а обработчик будет читать поток, пока не наткнется на разделитель, сформирует один запрос, обработает его, и благополучно забудет о нем.

Я очень бегло пробежался по классу архиватора и не могу сказать, умеет ли он дописывать архивы свежими файлами. Если да - то нужно просто получить список файлов и пройтись по каждому, дописывая его в конец архива. Если все написано хорошо и нигде не течет память - все пройдет великолепно и почти не будет жрать памяти. Я бы, впрочем, попробовал обычный [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.ziparchive.php) из стандартной библиотеки PHP - не могу сказать, считывает ли он архив при открытии, но если нет, то у него есть весь необходимый функционал на борту.

Мне сложно представить ситуацию, когда не хватит памяти на список файлов. Но если такая проблема возникнет, у нее вполне аналогичное решение: список файлов по мере заполнения скидывается в самый обычный временной файл, а при добавлении файлов в архив этот временной файл построчно читается (насколько понимаю, SplFileObject уже реализует необходимый итератор), в результате чего в памяти единомоментно висит всего один путь к файлу.

> Необходимо научить скрипт архивировать большие файлы так, чтобы не отваливался `memory_limit()`, `max_execution_time()`.

Забудьте про `max_execution_time`. Временной лимит существует только для того, чтобы склонная к повисанию страница не нарушала работу остальных и не устроила denial of service на сервере при многочисленном одновременном запросе. Здесь же изначально предполагается жручий функционал, мы заранее знаем, что время выполнения невозможно предугадать, и что его смерть недопустима, и он не должен выполняться в контексте веб-запроса. Он должен выполняться как отдельный процесс, если к этому обязательно надо прикрутить веб-морду - gearman в помощь. Реализовывать итерацию через аякс-запросы - это боль и ад, это не нужно.

> Какие варианты смогут решить задачу с копированием из одной папки на сервере в другую папку\архив zip того же сервера большой файл размером от 1 гб, есть ли возможность загружать память поэтапно, копируя файл последовательно\частями?

Да, лучше всего просто вызвать системную команду (не удивлюсь, если `copy()` и так все правильно сделает), можно открыть через `fopen()` и читать/писать по N байт.

> Как просканировать гигантскую директорию с кучей поддиректорий в разных итерациях и в итоге сложить все дерево папок и файлов в текстовый файл например\или в бд?

```
<?php
$path = '/tmp/';

$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$recursiveDirectoryIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    // $item - либо папка, либо файл
}
```

> Вообще, какая самая распространенная файловая система на шаредах, подскажите?

Скорее всего какой-нибудь ext3/ext4. Однако я не думаю, что где-нибудь получится вот так поиграть на шареде.